# Can I install Intel graphics installer for one version on the next version?

Tags: intel-graphics

On the [intel site for open source](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/) there is graphic installer available to download for 13.10, but not yet for 14.04. Can I install graphic for 13.10 on 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Intel Drivers available 14 May 2014

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.5-linux

Answer (score 1):

No the 13.10 deb will not install on 14.04.

You can try building from source and installing from there.

Download and extract the source from:
https://download.01.org/gfx/src/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.4.tar.gz

I ran ./configure but got stuck at:

```
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found<br/>
No package 'gio-2.0' found<br/>
No package 'polkit-gobject-1' found<br/>
No package 'packagekit-glib2' found<br/>
No package 'libsoup-gnome-2.4' found<br/>
No package 'gmodule-2.0' found<br/>
```

I don't feel like installing all of these packages individually since gtk+-3.0 is more than 4GB.

Maybe someone else with more experience can take it from here?

**UPDATE:**
Available May 14th:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.5-linux

Although this did not work for me, on both my machines, I got stuck at:

```
Finished : E:GPG error: http://download.01.org trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)  [  ] ◦
main-window.c/on_transaction_finished: Package transaction finished with an error
```

I guess we just have to wait for Intel to fix their repo?